# ASP.NET Core 3.1 - Json Request property to action method parameter model binding

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am migrating an app from ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core MVC.

Looks like ASP.NET Core model binding doesn't support binding of top level properties of json object to action method property binding (this was supported in ASP.NET MVC framework).

Example: I have an action method like this:

```
ActionResult UpdateSomethingOnPost(string name, string id) { }
```

I am posting Json body as below. It doesn't bind property "name" to "name" action method parameter, also "id" to "id" action method parameter.

```
{
    name: "Sachin",
    id: "1000"
}
```

What changes do I need to make to let this supported in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: In asp.net core you cannot directly pass through json, and then accept it with separate variables. You have two ways to change it. First, `change the receiving parameters type`, use a model to receive which contains the name and id fields. Another method is to change the mode of passing parameters, `change the json to form`, or pass the parameters in the form of route by changing the route.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding the `[HttpPost]` and `[FromBody]` attributes?

```cs
[HttpPost]
ActionResult UpdateSomethingOnPost([FromBody]string name, [FromBody]string id)
{
  // blah blah blah 
}
```

[This post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#frombody-inference-notes) mentions that for **simple types** you need to add the `[FromBody]` attribute:

> #### FromBody inference notes
>
> `[FromBody]` isn't inferred for simple types such as string or int. Therefore, the `[FromBody]` attribute should be used for simple types when that functionality is needed.

Comment: given link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#frombody-inference-notes is specific to web api apps. I think I am looking for web apps.

for mvc the link is 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1#model-binding

even though, I tried this in my mvc app but it didn't work.
looks like option "SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters" is only for api controllers.(ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions)